# discord.py - Get channel permissions of user

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a command that lists the permissions that the user has in the current channel. I have tried using a function that adds permissions to a list and calling it in the command.

Unfortunately, this command sends all of the permissions that a member could possibly have, rather than the permissions that the member has currently. How could I edit my code into finding what permissions the member has currently?

```py
@commands.command()
async def perms(self, ctx, user):
     def _perms(ctx):
          perms = []

         for p in user.permissions_in(ctx.channel):
              perms.append(p[0])
            
         return perms
     
     await ctx.send(" ".join(_perms(ctx)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions), a discord.Permissions object defines the `__iter__`-method by returning a list of tuples `(permission_name, permission_value)`, where `permission_value` will be `True` if the member has the permission and `False` otherwise. You simply need to add a check if the value is true before appending the name to your list like so:

```py
for p in user.permissions_in(ctx.channel):
    if p[1] is True:
        perms.append(p[0])
```

---

That said, your definition of `_perms` is entirely unnecessary and your code can be improved/shortened quite a bit. The following one-liner should also do what you want:

```py
@commands.command()
async def perms(self, ctx, user):
     await ctx.send(" ".join(p[0] for p in user.permissions_in(ctx.channel) if p[1]))
```

On a general note, some precautions should be taken in case the user has no permissions on the channel (the bot can't send an empty message and will throw an error)