# How can I check perms for a specific channel?

Tags: discord.py

I want to create a function which deletes links if you don't have embed links permission. If any of your role has embed links perms at chat you will be able to send links but if you don't have perm you will not be able to send links the bot will delete it.

```
@client.on_message
async def perm(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel = client.get_channel(channel_id)):
    if (perm.embed_links == False):
        await ctx.channel.send("This link is not allowed!")
```

Comment: Hi, try to use `ctx.channel.overwrites`, have a look to the [overwrites attribute on the official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.overwrites).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py - Get channel permissions of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70676150/discord-py-get-channel-permissions-of-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the message author has the send embed links permission you can use a simple if statement:

```py
if not message.author.guild_permissions.embed_links:
   #do something
```

You're final code would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
  if not message.author.guild_permissions.embed_links: #checking if the message author has the permission
    await message.delete() #if the message author has no permission, then the message gets deleted
    await message.channel.send("This link is not allowed!") #sending a warning message
```